# Web API 2, OData v4 y Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Tengo un problema que no tengo idea cómo puedo solucionarlo.

Tengo una clase de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Message {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
      public string AddressIp { get; set; }
      public string English { get; set; }
      public string Spanish { get; set; }
      public string French { get; set; }
      public string Portuguese { get; set; }
}
```

Y otra clase así:

```
public class MessageDto
{
   public long Key { get; set; }
   public string MessageValue { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora bien, para obtener el mensaje en el idioma del usuario utilizó esta función:

```
public static string GetPropValue(object source)
{
   var propertyName = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Parent.EnglishName;

   return source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(source, null).ToString();
}
```

En mi controller `OData` tengo esto:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<MessageDto> Get()
{
   var messages = _messageService.Queryable();

   var messagesDto =  messages.ToList().Select(t => _messageFactory.GetMessageViewModel(t));

   return other.AsQueryable();
}
```

La función `GetMessageViewModel()` hace esto:

```
public MessageDto GetMessageViewModel(Message model)
{
   return new MessageDto
   {
      Key = model.Id,
      MessageValue = PropertyValueHelper.GetPropValue(model)
   };
}
```

Ahora bien, ¿es posible hacer lo mismo pero mediante el uso de `Automapper`?

Por ejemplo al momento de realizar el mapeo no tengo idea cómo hacerlo para la columna `MessageDto.MessageValue`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Message, MessageDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.MessageValue, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.???))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

Tampoco he logrado convertir en la clase donde realizo el mapeo el mensaje en el idioma del usuario:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Message, MessageDto>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.MessageValue = PropertyValueHelper.GetPropValue(src));
```

¿Alguien me puede orientar o apoyar a realizarlo?

Comment: Pues estaría muy bien si publicaras una respuesta explicándolo. :-)

Comment: No me funcionó, porque automapper no soporta proyecciones con objetos IQueryable

Answer (score 3):

Tengo algunas dudas al respecto de tu implementación , comenzando por

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Parent.EnglishName;
```

Este código es server side verdad? Esto te devuelve la Cultura en la cuenta de servicio que se ejecuta en el servidor, no la del cliente que inicia sesión en el servicio.

Ahora, si estás exponiendo los datos en oData el flujo a implementar sería que parte de los parámetros que se recibe en cada petición fuera el lenguaje en el que se desea recibir la respuesta.

- Sino hay lenguaje especificado, responder en un lenguaje por default
- Si el lenguaje especificado no existe, responder en un lenguaje por default

Así que el lenguaje lo determina la aplicación cliente por algún mecanismo y esta a su vez hace el request oData incluyendo en  los parámetros el lenguaje en el que desea recibir la respuesta.

Puede que por alguna regla de negocio esperes nunca tener más de 4 lenguajes o lenguajes diferentes a los especificados, sin embargo la implementación

```
public class Message {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
      public string AddressIp { get; set; }
      public string English { get; set; }
      public string Spanish { get; set; }
      public string French { get; set; }
      public string Portuguese { get; set; }
}
```

luce bastante hardcodeada, por lo que sugeriría utilizar un diccionario que en efecto se creo para solucionar este tipo de escenarios

```
public class Message {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
      public string AddressIp { get; set; }
      public Dictionary<string, string> MessageContent{ get; set; }
}
```

Si la cantidad de mensajes no es tan grande como para persistirlos en una BD entonces mi recomendación sería utilizar archivos de recursos y accederlos por el nombre completo de acuerdo al idioma seleccionado.

Otra opción es persistirlos de todas maneras y utilizar Redis Cache para todo el tema de estas cadenas.

Comment: Juan Carlos: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó mucho para tomar la mejor decisión. El código por el que preguntas si es server side y para obtener el lenguaje utilizo algo similar a lo que está en el siguiente link: https://enginepit.com/2014/04/25/use-a-message-handler-to-set-asp-net-web-api-current-culture/ en donde establezco el idioma por default en caso de que no se envíe

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La solución que tengo actualmente es esta:

1. Crear una clase que contenga los idiomas a manejar

   ```
   [ComplexType]
   public class LocalizedString
   {
      public string English { get; set; }
      public string Spanish { get; set; }
      public string French { get; set; }
      public string Portuguese { get; set; }

      [NotMapped]
      public string Current
      {
         get { return (string)LanguageProperty().GetValue(this, null); }
         set { LanguageProperty().SetValue(this, value, null); }
      }

      public override string ToString()
      {
         return Current;
      } 

      private PropertyInfo LanguageProperty()
      {
         string currentLanguage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName;
     return GetType().GetProperty(currentLanguage);
      }
   }
   ```
2. La clase modelo deberá contener una propiedad de tipo `LocalizedString`

   ```
   public class Message
   {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
      public LocalizedString Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Tener un mapeo de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   private static void CreateMaps()
   {
      string language = null;
      Mapper.CreateMap<LocalizedString, string>().ProjectUsing(src =>
         language == "English" ? src.English :
         language == "Spanish" ? src.Spanish :
         language == "French" ? src.French :
         src.Portuguese);

      Mapper.CreateMap<Message, MessageViewModel>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
         .ForMember(dest => dest.MessageValue, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
   }
   ```
4. En mi controlador `OData` hago esto:

   ```
   public IQueryable<MessageViewModel> Get()
   {
      var messages = _messageService.Queryable();
      return messages.ProjectTo<MessageViewModel>(new { language = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Parent.EnglishName });
   }
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la edición. Saludos